# GUI to validate username

Tags: java

I have a code below, so I wanna make a GUI for login to make travel class, Here I make some Regex for username, that should be a-z with 0-9 and - or _ only, minimum 3 and maximum 15 but whenever I type 'm' or 'm@'it always show Message Dialog success and it should be wrong, can someone please check my code below, what's missing actually?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    String USERNAME_PATTERN = "^[a-z0-9_-]{3,15}$";

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(USERNAME_PATTERN);
                    Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher(uname.getText());

                    if (!regexMatcher.matches()) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Success");
                        travel launch = new travel();
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username / Password is Wrong");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
```

Comment: Remove "!" from "if (!regexMatcher.matches()) {"

Comment: You have the condition reversed, it shows the success dialog if the regex does NOT match.